# Insert Values from another Row and handle row does not exist. Mysql insert

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I have a question/answer system and am trying to record response time when a question is replied to.

Simple snippet of the `INSERT` code I am using:

```
 INSERT INTO questions (responsetime, {otherfields})
 (SELECT Now-msgDateTime, {otherfields} FROM questions WHERE headerid='This_Header_id' ORDER    BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This works absolutely fine for all secondary messages in a thread, but for the first message in a thread it will have a new and unique `HeaderId`, so a query

```
(SELECT * FROM questions WHERE headerid='This_Header_id')
```

Will return no values. In this case, my first SQL update will not `INSERT` a new row.

So how do I write a fallback to insert '0' into the `responsetime` field where the row selected by `headerid` is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a group by function like MAX which will return either null or a matching value.  If there's a better way to do it, would love to see other answers but suspect this will work for you.

```
INSERT INTO questions (responsetime, {otherfields})
 (SELECT IF(ISNULL(MAX(headerid)), 0, Now-msgDateTime)
   , {otherfields} 
  FROM questions WHERE headerid='This_Header_id' 
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Ah, that's brilliant. Thanks! :)